# java8 parallel string statistics / stream / map/reduce

Tags: java, performance, mapreduce, java-stream, word-count

I have a very long string in java and I am trying to get statistics of that string.

For example String s = "afafaf"

And I want to get all counts for all existing substrings with length 2.
For this small example from above this would be:

"af" - 3
"fa" - 2

Another example:
String s = "hsdjs"

Result:
"hs" - 1
"sd" - 1
"dj" - 1
"js" - 1

What I did and what is working was going over the string with for (int i=0; i < s.length;i++) and iterating Map entries.

Problem is that is damn slow.
I was thinking maybe the new Java8 functions for parallel processing might help me. But unfortuntely I wasn't able to get something running...maybe someone can help me out.

Current code:

```
    import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;


    String inputString = s;
    HashMultiset<String> multi = HashMultiset.create();

    for (int i=0;i <inputString.length()-1;i++) {             
        String aktuellerString = inputString.substring(i, i+2);
        multi.add(aktuellerString);       
    }
```

Here is the current profiling:
http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160909/naadsfxi.png

The add() method of HashMultiset of the google guava library actually takes most time overall. But this was the fastest collection I could find. (tried several other optimized libraries including normal HashMap, Tie, GS Collections,gnu.trove.map.hash.THashMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap, ...).

Thats why I thought that parallel processing might be the only way to speed up.

Comment: "iterating Map entries"? You mean iterate the map _during_ string scanning?

Comment: You should show what you have tried—both, classic and Stream variants. There are likely efficiency mistakes that can be solved without Stream or parallel processing. And independently we could find out why your Stream attempt doesn’t work.

Comment: The ideal structure for this kind of work is a trie. Apache commons has an implementation. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html But i'd start with a plain `HashMap<String, Integer>`

Comment: When using a map/reduce approach, make sure that your strings overlap. Splitting "afaf" to "af" and "af" will miss one "fa". Instead, split to "af" and "faf", i.e. always prepend the last character of the previous string.

Comment: Thx so far for the helpful comments: @ Marko actually I am using com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset this was the fastest solution. I also tried normal HashMap and several others. (also Trie). Think by altering the collection I cannot gain much more speed. I rather thought of parallel processing. I am currently cleaning my code, that I can give you a simple example how it currently works. I will also give you profiling results that you can get a better picture.

Comment: You'd use a Trie in a very different manner than a Map. The point is that it wouldn't require any string instantiation, as opposed to creating substrings for the map.

Comment: It’s not clear for what you would need a `HashMultiset` here. As said, post your code.

Comment: Used it, because it is faster

Comment: Faster than *what*? You should show with what you compare. Besides, the profiling result clearly shows that your benchmark is not correct. If you did sufficient warmup, `ClassLoader.loadClass` never showed up…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: As Marko points out, the cost of creating sub Strings is significant and even with multiple CPUs you can do better by having a structure which avoids creating them.  In this case we have only two characters and these can be encoded as an `int` value. In this case we could assume ASCII characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    char[] chars = new char[1000000000];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        chars[i] = (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    String s = new String(chars);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<String, Integer> freq = IntStream.range(0, s.length() - 1).parallel()
            .mapToObj(i -> s.substring(i, i + 2))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Took " + time + " ms " + freq);
}
```

prints

```
Took 8401 ms {aa=1479201, ab=1478451, ac=1479055, ...
```

However, if we use `collect` directly we can use a structure which doesn't create any objects.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    char[] chars = new char[1000000000];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        chars[i] = (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    String s = new String(chars);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] freqArr = IntStream.range(0, s.length() - 1).parallel()
            .collect(() -> new int[128 * 128],
                    (arr, i) -> arr[s.charAt(i) * 128 + s.charAt(i + 1)]++,
                    (a, b) -> sum(a, b));
    Map<String, Integer> freq = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < freqArr.length; i++) {
        int c = freqArr[i];
        if (c == 0) continue;
        String key = "" + (char) (i >> 7) + (char) (i & 0x7f);
        freq.put(key, c);
    }
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Took " + time + " ms " + freq);
}

static int[] sum(int[] a, int[] b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] += b[i];
    return a;
}
```

prints the following which is ~20x faster.

```
Took 404 ms {aa=1479575, ab=1480511, ac=1476255,
```

This makes a big difference because we are dealing with small strings

---

You can replace

```
for (int i=0; i < s.length;i++) { something(i) }
```

with

```
IntStream.range(0, s.length()).parallel().forEach(i -> { something(i) })
```

but a better solution is to use a mapping...

```
String s = "afafaffafafafffafaaaf";

Map<String, Long> freq = IntStream.range(0, s.length()-1).parallel() // 1
        .mapToObj(i -> s.substring(i, i + 2)) // 2
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting())); //3

System.out.println(freq);
```

1. Go through all the indexes for which there will be a two character
   string, in parallel.
2. Obtain each of the two character Strings for those indexes.
3. Concurrently group by name, the count of all the number of occurrences.

prints

```
{ff=3, aa=2, af=8, fa=7}
```

On Holger's point about groupingByConcurrent being potentially slower I tested four cases.

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<Integer, Long> freq = IntStream.range(0,1000000000)/*.parralel()*/
            .mapToObj(i -> i % 10)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy/*Concurrent*/(w -> w, Collectors.counting()));
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Took " + time+" ms " + freq);

without parallel(), with groupingBy : Took 14156 ms {0=100000000, 1=100000000, 2=100000000, 3=100000000, 4=100000000, 5=100000000, 6=100000000, 7=100000000, 8=100000000, 9=100000000}
with parallel(), with groupingBy : Took 5581 ms {0=100000000, 1=100000000, 2=100000000, 3=100000000, 4=100000000, 5=100000000, 6=100000000, 7=100000000, 8=100000000, 9=100000000}
without parallel(), with groupingByConcurrent : Took 38218 ms {0=100000000, 1=100000000, 2=100000000, 3=100000000, 4=100000000, 5=100000000, 6=100000000, 7=100000000, 8=100000000, 9=100000000}
with parallel(), with groupingByConcurrent : Took 27619 ms {0=100000000, 1=100000000, 2=100000000, 3=100000000, 4=100000000, 5=100000000, 6=100000000, 7=100000000, 8=100000000, 9=100000000}
```

Using groupingBy was the best solution, parallel or not.

Using Holger's comment further, by using `summingInt` this proved faster again.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Map<Integer, Integer> freq = IntStream.range(0, 1000000000).parallel()
        .mapToObj(i -> i % 10)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println("Took " + time+" ms " + freq);
```

prints

```
Took 4131 ms {0=100000000, 1=100000000, 2=100000000, 3=100000000, 4=100000000, 5=100000000, 6=100000000, 7=100000000, 8=100000000, 9=100000000}
```

Comment: Note that in the current implementation, `counting()` is not a *concurrent* collector, which will cause the `groupingByConcurrent` collector to *synchronize* on the group’s container. This can lead to a performance worse than `groupingBy`, which might already be worse than sequential execution for most strings…

Comment: @Holger are you sure? If so what is `counting` defined in such a way to support support accumulation of results in different threads?

Comment: @Holger Good point. A simple test suggests you can get slower results.

Comment: All collectors support accumulation in different threads. A concurrent collector has a thread safe accumulator function. All other collectors are used by letting the accumulator function work on a thread-local container, then using the *combiner* function for merging the results of different threads. Using a non-concurrent collector as sub-collector of a concurrent collector requires the concurrent collector to make the accumulator function thread-safe, as the combiner won’t be called.

Comment: @Holger I have updated my answer with some performance results. Is this what you might expect?

Comment: At least, I’m not surprised. By the way, `counting()` surprisingly does a reduction of boxed `Integer`s (at least in Java 8, should change in Java 9), so `summingInt(()->1)` might be even faster for larger numbers of elements…

Comment: @Holger `summingInt(e ->1)` was faster for parallel and serial.

Comment: Wow you are really fast guys....:) I now tried this one: Map<String, Long> freq = IntStream.range(0, s.length()-1).parallel() // 1
        .mapToObj(i -> s.substring(i, i + 2)) // 2
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, Collectors.counting())); //3

and it is already way faster than my initial version see here: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4473/4elplcow_png and here http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4473/qgaaj6c3_png

Comment: @stats0007 `summingInt` appears to be even faster.

Comment: yeah, I want to try this - sorry that I am always answering so late.... to be honest it is because it  takes me always some time to understand and reproduce in my mind what you are doing.

Comment: groupingByConcurrent + without parallel -> 34 seconds,   groupingBy + without parallel -> 33 seconds, groupingBy + with parallel -> 10 seconds, groupingByConcurrent + with parallel 11 seconds.

Comment: this are the results for my file... so seems parallel is faster, while groupingByConcurrent doesn't change much --- by the way I am reading in a text file (basically the first 100.000.000 bytes of wikipedia some years ago) http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/compression/enwik8.zip

Comment: now tried the summingInt approach -> now it takes 7s for my example file....nearly 3 times faster than my initial approach, nice :)

Comment: `groupingBy` uses a `HashMap`, but it may be worth to try out a solution with a Trie of `char`s, which means you'd never have to instantiate the substrings, calculate the hashcode, or compare against strings in the same bucket. Memory representation would be more compact as well. https://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Using an `int[]` is 20x faster. I have updated my answer ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Holy smokes!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik indeed, surprised I didn't think of it thank you.

Comment: wow, I am really amazed, how much performance can be yielded with more knowledge. @Peter, unfortunately I could not get the newest update running for my data: I just copied your code and took my String s - instead of yours and I get this: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 79812  (occuring in the collect part of the code). My first idea was that maybe my String isn't ASCII so I replaced all 128 with 256...but that didn't work either, just gave me the same error at 94148

Comment: @stats0007 94148/256 is ~368. You might need to use `512` instead of 128. Or you might need to scan the whole file looking for the highest character. One way to avoid creating a very large array is to combine a smaller array for common characters and have a `Map<String, Integer>` for the higher ones.

Comment: Ah forgot to mention, you were right, this was the problem. Had some high characters in it. Thx again :)